# Unable to install docker on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, docker-machine

I am unable to install docker on Ubuntu server.

The Error:

```
1.Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'stable/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
2.Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/spring/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found  
3.Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My sources.list file looks like :

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable   
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```

Also I am trying to install docker in virtual environment within Ubuntu server and above sources.list file in sources.list file within root folder.

I am trying to install docker as perquisite for my hyper ledger network set up?

Comment: try out these steps https://grizzlybit.info/2020-04-11-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like docker doesn't have Sources. But you are looking for binaries anyway. So remove the deb-src line.

The second errormust come from a different sources.list file, check /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, too.

But both of these aren't stopping you. The missing index files will simply be ignored. They aren't stopping you from installing docker so your problem must be something else not stated in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all docker entries from /etc/apt/sources.list and also delete all /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker*

Then simply use this script as root:

```
curl https://get.docker.com | bash
```

Or as user:

```
curl https://get.docker.com | sudo bash
```

Then install it via edited script (deleted docker install)

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Razikus/6b61af8c69e563d587201c34f5c66568/raw/5608cdb81e33650b70ac934e261bbd5410269f7a/prereqs-ubuntu.sh | bash
```

According to comment, differences between original and changed:

[image: Differences between original and changed]

Check diff from CLI:

```
diff <(curl https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/prereqs-ubuntu.sh) <(curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Razikus/6b61af8c69e563d587201c34f5c66568/raw/5608cdb81e33650b70ac934e261bbd5410269f7a/prereqs-ubuntu.sh)
```

It will be faster than searching for error

Comment: Hi, Actually I am not directly installing docker but installing prerequisites for hyperledger framework using a single command for all downloads :                     curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh

./prereqs-ubuntu.sh  , In this case what can be done ? Should I remove all entries of docker and run the command - './prereqs-ubuntu.sh'

Comment: remove all entries of docker (delete also file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list)

install docker via command curl https://get.docker.com | bash

then install your version via this script: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Razikus/6b61af8c69e563d587201c34f5c66568/raw/5608cdb81e33650b70ac934e261bbd5410269f7a/prereqs-ubuntu.sh

I deleted entries with docker

Comment: Oh yeah, run random scripts downlaoded from the internet unseen as root. Great advice, NOT.

Comment: added diff and diff check for scripts